# Unresolved loginManager Facebook SDK swift3

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3, cocoapods

im working with Facebook SDK in swift3

Frist int my pod:

```
target ‘ProcIOS’ do
pod 'MOCA'
pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 2.0.0'
pod 'AMTooltip'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
use_frameworks!
end
```

Second , header

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

Third

appdelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        MOCA.initializeSDK()
        FIRApp.configure()
        let bool = SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        FBSDKProfile.enableUpdates(onAccessTokenChange: true)
        return bool
    }

 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
```

And final in my app:

```
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin
let loginManager = LoginManager()

Show me: Use unresolved identifier LoginManager
```

I clean the project, reinstall cocoa pods, delete all pods except Facebook sdk, but the result is same?
what im doing wrong?

Comment: let loginManager:FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager() use this

Comment: in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions `let bool = SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)` must be `let bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)` may be this is problem

Comment: LoginManager comes in android check this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager

Comment: Try it, by adding facebook sdk framework files in project, instead of pod install.

Comment: `FBSDKLoginManager.initialize()`  // Initialize facebook login inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your appdelegate as below :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
     return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

**AND**

```
import FacebookCore
```